# I tried to get free plugin but unable to find the word press plugin?

Tags: wordpress

"But version problem is coming. my current version is 4.0 but available is WordPress Version: 4.7.0 or higher. I tried but it's not installing"

[wp-job-manager-wp-plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-job-manager/)

I have searched the plugin based on apply job and interview process with in the company , but i did't find. Could any body help me.

I am using mysql connection to connect database, once i changed the version it will effect. i am also using groups plugin and buddy press plugin and i am also developed customised plugin using php and mysql. Could you please help me how to do.

Comment: do ask such questions here. It a place for solving a problem which you started

Answer (score 0):

Please try WP Job Manager which is a free plugin for adding job-board functionality to your WordPress site.  Being shortcode based, it can work with any theme (given a bit of CSS styling) and is really simple to setup.  You can download it from [here](http://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/wp-job-manager.latest-stable.zip).

Comment: But version problem is coming. my current version is 4.0 but available is WordPress Version: 4.7.0 or higher. I tried but it's not installing

Comment: Then you should download an older version of the plugin from here  https://github.com/Automattic/WP-Job-Manager/archive/1.25.3.zip